# Regex on a string of XML type using c#

Tags: xml, regex, c#-4.0

Input is of the format shown below :

```
<HiddenRowGroups>
    <HiddenGroup>
      <From>16</From>
      <To>17</To>
      <Level>0</Level>
      <GroupName>TABS</GroupName>
      <ItemTotalHeader>Total</ItemTotalHeader>
    </HiddenGroup>
    <HiddenGroup>
      <From>3</From>
      <To>3</To>
      <Level>0</Level>
      <GroupName>ABSCDXH</GroupName>
      <ItemTotalHeader>Total</ItemTotalHeader>
    </HiddenGroup>
  </HiddenRowGroups>
```

Desired Output : `<HiddenRowGroups />`

How to replace the regex which is in form of a string to `<HiddenRowGroups />` . I tried replacing it via `Regex.Replace` method of C#.

Comment: _What_ are you trying to accomplish? What are you trying to replace? What regex are you using? Why aren't you using one of the XML APIs to work with XML?

Comment: I am working on C# code. This xml is actually XAML grid which i serialize into string and save it into the database. As mentioned in the question above i have given both input and output(result) i want to achieve. Let me know if i answered your questions.

Comment: Do not do this with regex. Regex is completely unsuited to this task. Use XSLT. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Comment: Hello Jim , I tried playing around with it but couldn't find an appropriate answer

Comment: Are you trying to remove all the elements inside of `<HiddenRowGroups>`?

Comment: Yes correct. and i got the solution as well. Was testing it <HiddenRowGroups>[\d\w\s\W\D]*<\/HiddenRowGroups> .Thanks for your time and help.